# how to let my code works for 7-segment digital clock in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`enter code here`code below is for the 7-segment digital clock implemented in css HTML and javascript .However, i tried to implement javascript here  but my code  is not working obviously.I created digitSegments for number from 0 to 9 in array when they are ON (red led is on )and i'm trying to do it in a simple javascript code like if-else since i'm a beginner .Iwould be thankful if you hepled 
 and thanks in advance

```js
var digitSegments = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6], //6

    [2,3],//2
    [1,2,7,5,4],//5
    [1,2,7,3,4],//5
    [6,7,2,3],//4
    [1,6,7,3,4],//5
    [1,6,5,4,3,7],//6
    [1,2,3], //3
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],//7
    [1,2,7,3,6]//5
]

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var _hours = document.querySelectorAll('.hours');
  var _minutes = document.querySelectorAll('.minutes');
  var _seconds = document.querySelectorAll('.seconds');
  
  setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours(), minutes = date.getMinutes(), seconds = date.getSeconds();  
    if(_hours/10 <10 ){
setNumber=(_hours[0], 0 , 1);
setNumber=(_hours[1], hours%10, 1);
    }
    else{
      setNumber(_hours[0], parseInt(hours/10), 1);
    setNumber(_hours[1], hours%10, 1);
    }
   

    if(_minutes/10 <10 ){
setNumber=(_minutes[0], 0 , 1);
setNumber=(_minutes[1], minutes%10, 1);
    }
    else{
      setNumber(_minutes[0], parseInt(minutes/10), 1);
    setNumber(_minutes[1], minutes%10, 1);
    }

    if(_seconds/10 <10 ){
setNumber=(_seconds[0], 0 , 1);
setNumber=(_seconds[1], seconds%10, 1);
    }
    else{
      setNumber(_seconds[0], parseInt(seconds/10), 1);
    setNumber(_seconds[1], seconds%10, 1);
    }
    
    
  }, 1000);
});


var setNumber = function (digit , number , on)
{
  var segments = digit.querySelectorAll('.segment');

  if (date.getSeconds==digitSegments[6] && date.getSeconds==digitSegments[0]){
    segments[digitSegment-1].classList.add('on');
  }

  else if(date.getMinutes == digitSegments[6] && date.getMinutes ==digitSegments[0]){
    
  }
  else  if(date.getHours == digitSegments[2] && date.getHours == digitSegments[4]){

    
  }
}
```

```css
.clock {
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:900px;
    margin-left:-450px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  
  .digit {
    width:120px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 5px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
  }
  
  .digit .segment {
    background:#c00;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.15;
    transition:opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition:opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s;
  }
  
  .digit .segment.on, .separator {
    opacity:1;
    box-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
    transition:opacity 0s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0s;
    -ms-transition:opacity 0s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0s;
    -o-transition:opacity 0s;
  }
  
  .separator {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:#c00;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:-90px;
  }
  
  .digit .segment:nth-child(1) {
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    height:10px;
  }
  
  .digit .segment:nth-child(2) {
    top:20px;
    right:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:75px;
    height:calc(50% - 25px);
  }
  
  .digit .segment:nth-child(3) {
    bottom:20px;
    right:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:75px;
    height:calc(50% - 25px);
  }
  
  .digit .segment:nth-child(4) {
    bottom:10px;
    right:20px;
    height:10px;
    left:20px;
  }
  
  .digit .segment:nth-child(5) {
    bottom:20px;
    left:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:75px;
    height:calc(50% - 25px);
  }
  
  .digit .segment:nth-child(6) {
    top:20px;
    left:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:75px;
    height:calc(50% - 25px);
  }
  
  .digit .segment:nth-child(7) {
    bottom:95px;
    bottom:calc(50% - 5px);
    right:20px;
    left:20px;
    height:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="clock">
        <div class="digit hours">
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="digit hours">
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="separator"></div>
      
        <div class="digit minutes">
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="digit minutes">
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="separator"></div>
      
        <div class="digit seconds">
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="digit seconds">
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
          <div class="segment"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: you have references to non existent variable `now` and `date` variable is in the wrong scope.  getElementById is referencing a class.  you're treating methods getMinutes like a property, trying to increment it.  And is there a reason you are trying to manipulate values on the current date object?  Why not just retrieve the current time?  You are also trying to act on numbers in string form before they've been cast to numbers.  There are too many problems with the code.

Comment: @user120242 i'm trying to control segments(ON or OFF) at current time , for example when seconds reach 60 let the segments of number 1 in minutes be ON as 01 and so on for hours

Comment: I see.  Is this for the purpose of an exercise and learning or is it something you just need a solution for?  I would recommend just retrieving the time on the interval loop instead of calculating and manipulating the date object when you don't have to.  And even then you would be better off just manipulating the timestamp (milliseconds since epoch) just for ease of use.  You are just trying to display a digital clock synced to current time right?

Comment: @user120242 actually i'm a student and i'm trying to learn js as much as possible and i need this solution .and yes i'm trying to display a segmented digital clock showing the current time but i failed in js code here

Comment: You code has tons of typos. You need setNumber( instead of setNumber =  and you need to make the date global if you use it later and you need () on getSeconds etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks a bit better when `.segment` having opacity `0.05`

```js
const digitSegments = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [2, 3],
  [1, 2, 7, 5, 4],
  [1, 2, 7, 3, 4],
  [6, 7, 2, 3],
  [1, 6, 7, 3, 4],
  [1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 2, 7, 3, 6]
];



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const _hours = document.querySelectorAll('.hours');
  const _minutes = document.querySelectorAll('.minutes');
  const _seconds = document.querySelectorAll('.seconds');

  clearClasses = function(childArray) {
    childArray.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove("on")
    });
  }

  setValueSectionValue = function(section, value) {
    clearClasses(section[0].querySelectorAll('.segment'));
    clearClasses(section[1].querySelectorAll('.segment'));
    if (value < 10) {
      setDigit(section[0], 0)
      setDigit(section[1], value)
    } else {
      setDigit(section[0], (value - value % 10) / 10)
      setDigit(section[1], value % 10)
    }
  }
  setDigit = function(parentDigitElement, value) {
    const childElements = parentDigitElement.querySelectorAll('.segment')
    const digitIndices = digitSegments[value];
    for (const item of digitIndices) {
      childElements[item - 1].classList.add("on")
    }
  }

  let lastTimeStr = ''
  setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    const currentTimeStr = `${date.getHours()}${date.getMinutes()}${date.getSeconds()}`
    if (lastTimeStr === currentTimeStr) {
      return;
    }

    setValueSectionValue(_hours, date.getHours())
    setValueSectionValue(_minutes, date.getMinutes())
    setValueSectionValue(_seconds, date.getSeconds())

    lastTimeStr = `${date.getHours()}${date.getMinutes()}${date.getSeconds()}`;
  }, 100)
});
```

```css
.clock {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: -450px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.digit {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.digit .segment {
  background: #c00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.03;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.digit .segment.on,
.separator {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0s;
}

.separator {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #c00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
}

.digit .segment:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 10px;
}

.digit .segment:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 75px;
  height: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.digit .segment:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 75px;
  height: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.digit .segment:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 20px;
}

.digit .segment:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 75px;
  height: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.digit .segment:nth-child(6) {
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 75px;
  height: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.digit .segment:nth-child(7) {
  bottom: 95px;
  bottom: calc(50% - 5px);
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="digit hours">
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit hours">
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="separator"></div>

  <div class="digit minutes">
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit minutes">
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="separator"></div>

  <div class="digit seconds">
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="digit seconds">
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain    valFound = digitIndices.find(x => x === i + 1)
                        if (valFound === i + 1) {
                            childElements[i].classList.add("on") ,?

Comment: You can replace `for (let i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
                        valFound = digitIndices.find(x => x === i + 1)
                        if (valFound === i + 1) {
                            childElements[i].classList.add("on")
                        }
                    }`    **with**   `for (const item of digitIndices) {
                      childElements[i-1].classList.add("on")
                    } `